# Using Streambuilder with Flutter and GoRouter to persist User State

Tags: flutter

Anyone used Streambuilder with Flutter and GoRouter before to persist User state?

Currently, I'm using the default Flutter navigation and it's working fine (see below) but I'm trying to replace with GoRouter now

My previous navigation setup using default Flutter navigation

```
home: StreamBuilder(
           stream: AuthMethods().authChanges,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
               );
             }

             if (snapshot.hasData) {
               return const TabsScreen();
            }

            return const AuthScreen();
           }),
    );
   }
```

My current goRouter code. I'm wondering where I can use Streambuilder in d code below to persist user state for my app (or whether Streambuilder can be used at all with go router)

```
GoRouter routeConstruct() {
  return GoRouter(
    routes: <RouteBase>[
      GoRoute(
          path: '/',
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            return const PublicScreen();
          },
          routes: <RouteBase>[
            GoRoute(
              path: Events_Screen,
              builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                return const EventsScreen();
              },
            ),
            GoRoute(
              path: "$EventDetail_Screen/:eventId",
              builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                return EventDetailScreen(eventId: state.params['eventId']!);
              },
            ),
            ...
          ]),
    ],
  );
```

Can I use Streambuilder with Flutter and GoRouter to persist User authentication state? If can, where in the goRouter code can I use Streambuilder to determine which widget to show based on Auth state? Thanks

###########################

class AuthMethods

```
class AuthMethods {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Stream<User?> get authChanges => _auth.authStateChanges();
// --> use of bang ! operator here
  User get user => _auth.currentUser!;

  Future<bool> signInWithGoogle(BuildContext context) async {
    bool res = false;

    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth =
          await googleUser?.authentication;

      final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken, idToken: googleAuth?.idToken);

      UserCredential userCredential =
          await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

      User? user = userCredential.user;

      if (user != null) {
        if (userCredential.additionalUserInfo!.isNewUser) {
          await _firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
            'username': user.displayName,
            'uid': user.uid,
            'profilePhoto': user.photoURL,
          });
        }
        res = true;
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      showSnackBar(context, e.message!);
      res = false;
    }
    return res;
  }
```

class RouteNotifier

```
class RouterNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  RouterNotifier(this._authMethods) {
    _authMethods.authChanges.listen((event) {
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  final AuthMethods _authMethods;

  String? redirect(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
    final onLoginPage = state.location == '/$AuthScreen';
    final onHomePage = state.location == '/$Tabs_Screen';

// --> The getter 'isEmpty' isn't defined for the type 'User'.
// --> User get user => _auth.currentUser!; used a bang operator
    if (_authMethods.user.isEmpty && onHomePage) {
      return '/$AuthScreen';
    }

// --> The getter 'isEmpty' isn't defined for the type 'User'.
    if (_authMethods.currentUser.isNotEmpty && onLoginPage) {
      return '/$Tabs_Screen';
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

router.dart

```
GoRouter routeConstruct() {
  return GoRouter(
    refreshListenable: router,

    routes: <RouteBase>[
      GoRoute(
          path: '/',
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            return const PublicScreen();
          },
          routes: <RouteBase>[
            GoRoute(
              path: Events_Screen,
              builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                return const EventsScreen();
              },
            ),
            GoRoute(
              path: "$EventDetail_Screen/:eventId",
              builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                return EventDetailScreen(eventId: state.params['eventId']!);
              },
            ),
          ]),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify why you have problems with migration to GoRouter?

Comment: I'm not sure where I can use Streambuilder in the goRouter codes or can I even use Streambuilder at all? I have just added my current code above

Comment: Your question is unclear, sorry. Can you rephrase it and add more context?

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm migrating from the default Flutter router to go router. Presently, I'm using Streambuilder to persist User state as demonstrated in my example code above. I'm not sure if I can use Streambuilder or where to use it with go router. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

before go router 5.0.0 :

go router has class called `GoRouterRefreshStream`, so in go router

```
GoRouter (
....
refreshListenable: GoRouterRefreshStream(AuthMethods().authChanges),
```

but after go router 5.0.0, they [remove it](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10l22o4ml4Ss83UyzqUC8_xYOv_QjZEi80lJDNE4q7wM/edit?pli=1&resourcekey=0-U-BXBQzNfkk4v241Ow-vZg)

so you must create your own notifier :

```
class RouterNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {


  RouterNotifier(this._authMethods) {
    _authMethods.authChanges.listen((event) {
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  final AuthMethods _authMethods;
}
```

on go Router:

```
GoRouter(
      debugLogDiagnostics: false,
      ....
      ...
      refreshListenable: RouterNotifier(AuthMethods()),
      ...
      );
```

> and how go router can work like stream builder you use before?

redirect come in handy:

```
final router  = RouterNotifier(AuthMethods());

GoRouter (
...
refreshListenable: router,
redirect: router.redirect,
```

in `RouterNotifier` class :

```
class RouterNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
    
    
      RouterNotifier(this._authMethods) {
        _authMethods.authChanges.listen((event) {
          notifyListeners();
        });
      }
    
      final AuthMethods _authMethods;

    String? redirect(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {

    final onLoginPage = state.location == '/login';
    final onHomePage = state.location == '/';

    if (_authMethods.currentUser.isEmpty && onHomePage) {

      return '/login';
    }

    if (_authMethods.currentUser.isNotEmpty && onLoginPage) {

      return '/';
    }


    return null;
  }
```

}

class User model :

```
class User {

String id;
.........
some variable i need from db;

static const empty = User(id: '');

bool get isEmpty => this == User.empty;
bool get isNotEmpty => this != User.empty;

}
```

on Stream :

```
Stream<User> get user {
    // map the user if user null is mean empty
    return _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().asyncMap((fUser) async {
      
      if (fUser == null) {
      const User user = User.empty;
      return user;
      } else {
      // in my case i need to take some data from Firestore 
      .... 
      await datafromDb() // if you dont need to wait future, remove async map, just use normal map
      return fUser.withBiodata();
```

Comment: Hi Sayyid, i am following Rivaan video on Youtube. He used a bang ! operator  on _auth.currentUser!when creating d getter user. as a result, i can't call isNotEmpty or isEmpty in RouterNotifier when determining which route to go to. Do you know how I can work around this? Thanks

Comment: currentUser `isEmpty` is just my User Model getter to get if Firebase user is null or not, i will update the answer if you need some example

Comment: i edit the answer, the idea is, map returned event from `authStateChanges().map(event)` , this event return a 'User' class from firebase, its contain additional variable like uid, googlePhoto, email, if this `event` is null, is mean user not authenticated

Comment: but i think, if you use _authMethods.currentUser != null its still the same. current User you get directly from firebase user, i just need to convert fUser to my Custom User model

Comment: i user riverpod for state management, but the concept i take from here : https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterfirebaselogintutorial

Comment: I found below github repo in another stackoverflow thread about using goRouter, Firebase and Flutter. It uses Riverpod. This might interest u https://github.com/lucavenir/go_router_riverpod/tree/master/firebase_example/lib